# How to add reference System.Net.Http.HttpClient inside .ashx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I am trying to include the  System.Net.Http.HttpClient inside .ashx page.

I have added the reference "System.Net.Http" (Version 4.0.0.0)

but my HttpClient is not appearing under System.Net.Http. I am getting the error as below.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new  System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
```

I am getting the error as below:

> the type 'HttpClient' defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Token..

I have tried by adding the reference in the web.config file.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Right click the project and click Add Reference if you want to add a reference to a .NET Framework assembly in the GAC. Or hit Manage NuGet packages if you want to reference an assembly provided via NuGet (I can't remember how System.Net.Http is distributed at the moment)

Comment: I have installed the 'System.Net.Http' by NuGet Version 4.0.0.0 and path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Net.Http.dll.

When I press Dot(.) after System.Net.Http Its giving me option as below insted of HttpClient 

System.Net.Http.Handlers

System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory or System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandlerExtensions

Comment: If you installed it via NuGet, it wouldn't be in that directory location.

Comment: I have again Installed after Uninstalled by Nuget. When I have checked the path under property. Its showing me 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Net.Http.dll'

Comment: I also have updated ny web.config file as 
<configuration>
    <system.web>
         <compilation>
             <assemblies>
                  <add assembly="System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
             </assemblies>
          </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: Have you remembered the `using System.Net.Http;`?

Comment: Yes I have added using syste.Net.Http  Also I am ging full name as System.Net.Http client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(). I am struggling this issue from last 2 days. I have tried all possible ways.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You wouldn't get that error from a missing using statement.

Comment: @susheeltyagi If you use `HttpClient client = new  HttpClient();` then VS will underline `HttpClient` and you can then hover over it and go to the suggested solutions. Choose the appropriate one and let VS do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

On your Solutions explorer, under your project tab right-click on references. Find "System.Net.Http" and check to add the reference.

Answer (score 1):

In the web.config file, you need to add System.Net.Http to the assemblies-section. 
Like System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement here

```
  <system.web>    
    <compilation debug="true" strict="true" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.JScript, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install the NuGet package for web API client.
In NuGet package manager search for 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'